# how to clear trusted server certificate cache in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ssl, https

I want the webview in my app to fail with the error NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted for each entrance to a site with an untrusted server certificate (so I will be able to show an alert to the user and decide whether to enter the site). 
Currently the error happens only in the first time, and if the user approved the site, the error doesn't happen again. 
How can I delete the trusted certificates cache, or make the request ignore the cache?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2232/_index.html has it all documented. It seems like you have a few options, but it isn't something I'm familiar with. Just a helpful nudge.